# Call return method through view controllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have two different view controllers ViewController.m & teacherList.m. I am trying to call the -(NSMutableArray *)getTeachersList method from teacherList.m to have it create an array for me and then be able to use it in ViewController.m. I want to do this just hard coding it and not with sequencing or use of storyboard

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "teacherList.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize userView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
NSMutableArray *hey = [teacherList getTeachersList];;

NSString *hello = [hey objectAtIndex:0];

[self say:hello];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)say:(NSString *)greet{
userView.text = greet;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

teacherList.m File

```
#import "teacherList.h"

@interface teacherList ()

@end

@implementation teacherList

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getTeachersList{
NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www2.qcc.mass.edu/facAbsence/default.asp"];



NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:website];



NSURLResponse* response = nil;

NSError *error = nil;

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

//storing data in a string

NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//putting it into an array to be

//able to working wiht string or array

NSArray *newString = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];


NSMutableArray *teacherArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableString *curLineNum;
NSString *curLine;

int i;

for (i = 0; i <[newString count]; i++) {

    curLine = [newString objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([curLine rangeOfString:@"<strong>"].location != NSNotFound) {

        NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:curLine];

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"<strong>" intoString:NULL];

        [theScanner setScanLocation: [theScanner scanLocation]+8];

        [theScanner scanUpToString:@"</strong>" intoString:&curLineNum];

        [teacherArray addObject:curLineNum];

    }

}
return teacherArray;

}


@end
```

Comment: What is the problem with your existing code?

Comment: Your code as-is will require an instance of teacherList to be defined. You can make the method, getTeachersList, a class method instead.

Comment: Re your now deleted question, find a iOS library that supports HTTP browsing with cookies programmatically. You'll need to submit your credentials in a POST operation, and not in a URL.

Comment: Thank you @halfer I will look into it and try to tag you one this if i run into anything but I should be able to figure it out when I am on the right track. I just had no idea how to do it.

Comment: No problem - I've no idea about iOS though, so ask a new question. Incidentally, whilst I appreciate the system here permits you to delete your questions, bear in mind it can inconvenience people who are in the middle of writing out an answer or a comment. If you get a few downvotes, don't worry about them; if you participate in answering here, you'll soon get the rep back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the method `getTeachersList` in a view controller. Create a singleton object that is a subclass of `NSObject`. Let's call it `TeacherListManager`.

Then ask the singleton for the teacher's list.

The call might look like this:

```
TeacherListManager *theTeacherListManager = [TeacherListManager sharedTeacherListManager];

NSMutableArray *theTeacherList = theTeacherListManager.teachersList;

if (theTeacherList == nil)
  //Handle the case where the teacher list hasn't been loaded yet.
```

Do a search on Objective C singleton design pattern for more information.

Your `getTeachersList` method is currently written to get the teachers list using synchronous networking calls, which is bad. If anything slows down the network connection then it can hang the UI for up to 2 minutes until the connection times out.

you should rewrite that method to download the data asynchronously.